# mysql :Select last 10 entry with column value TRUE and 10 witt value FALSE without repeating

Tags: mysql

can me someone telling the mysql schema, how can write 1 query for last 2x10 rows who 1 columns is TRUE or FALSE?

eg. I would like to receive last 10 records where column 'allapot' is true and
would to receive last 10 records where column 'allapop' is false and all without repeat.

Can someone help? Thank you.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this query:

```
select min(id),your_table.* from your_table
where allapot='TRUE' Limit 10
UNION select min(id), your_table.* from your_table
where allapot='FALSE' Limit 10
```